# Add blank line after every result in grep

Tags: linux, scripting, grep

my grep command looks like this
zgrep -B bb -A aa "pattern" *

I would lke to have output as:

```
file1:line1
file1:line2
file1:line3
file1:pattern
file1:line4
file1:line5
file1:line6
            </blank line>
file2:line1
file2:line2
file2:line3
file2:pattern
file2:line4
file2:line5
file2:line6
```

The problem is that its hard to distinguish when lines corresponding to the first found result end and the lines corresponding to the second found result start.

Note that although man grep says that "--" is added between contiguous group of matches. It works only when multiple matches are found in the same file. but in my search (as above) I am searching multiple files.

also note that adding a new blank line after every bb+aa+1 line won't work because what if a file has less than bb lines before the pattern.

Comment: grep -H will help distinguish outputs.

Comment: @WilliamPursell What does that do? I tried it but couldn't see any difference.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter `-H` just adds the filename to the start of each output. It is only different when only a single file is passed as an argument to grep.  It doesn't seem to actually help in this case, though.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for replying. Thought I was missing something. :)

Comment: See a working solution that uses sed in the following link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3128

Answer (score 26):

#### Pipe `|` any output to:

```
sed G
```

#### Example:

```
ls | sed G
```

#### If you `man sed` you will see

`G` Append's a newline character followed by the contents of the hold space to the pattern space.

Comment: This command adds newline not only between results, but also between the lines of a single result. So `grep -A1 pattern file | sed G` returns `result_0 <new line> the_line_after_result_0 <new  line>` instead of `result_0 the_line_after_result_0 <new  line>`.

Answer (score 21):

pipe grep output through

```
awk -F: '{if(f!=$1)print ""; f=$1; print $0;}'
```

Comment: It works and I upvoted, thanks! A downside is that I loose --color this way.

Comment: @moejoe, you get call `--color` back by turning it into `--color=always`, I think. Because by default color is suppressed if you output is not terminal, which it's not, when you pipe to other process.

Comment: You can always `grep` again. For the same string you `grep`ped for before to reintroduce the color syntax or to narrow down your search further. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find back the link, but this also works:
grep --include=\*.{md,txt} -rn -e "mypattern" --color=always | tee >(wc -l)

Comment: @user2718593, what is this supposed to achieve? This will count lines in grep's output, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this question?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker. It outputs what was asked in the example, though no blank line between files; of course you replace mypattern with the relevant one.

Comment: @user2718593, you confuse the hell out of me, I do not think it actually outputs what's asked, no before and after lines and the only thing OP asked for was a blank line? you basically added filename patterns and line numbers and I don't think OP asked for it?

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that its hard to distinguish when lines corresponding to the first found result end and the lines corresponding to the second found result start.
>
> Note that although man grep says that "--" is added between contiguous group of matches. It works only when multiple matches are found in the same file. but in my search (as above) I am searching multiple files.

If you don't mind a `--` in lieu of a `</blank line>`, add the `-0` parameter to your `grep`/`zgrep` command. This should allow for the `--` to appear even when searching multiple files. You can still use the `-A` and `-B` flags as desired.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the **--group-separator** parameter, with an empty value, so it'd just add a new-line.

```
some-stream | grep --group-separator=
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it with the -A and -B parameters so I can't say for sure but you could try using sed G as mentioned here on [Unix StackEx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/how-do-i-add-newlines-between-lines-printed-on-the-command-line). You'll loose coloring though if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for this in `grep` and I don't *think* there is a way to do it with `xargs` or `tr` (I tried), but here is a for loop that will do it (`for f in *; do grep -H "1" $f && echo; done`):

```
[ 11:58 jon@hozbox.com ~/test ]$ for f in *; do grep -H "1" $f && echo; done

a:1

b:1

c:1

d:1

[ 11:58 jon@hozbox.com ~/test ]$ ll
-rw-r--r--  1 jon  people     2B Nov 25 11:58 a
-rw-r--r--  1 jon  people     2B Nov 25 11:58 b
-rw-r--r--  1 jon  people     2B Nov 25 11:58 c
-rw-r--r--  1 jon  people     2B Nov 25 11:58 d
```

The `-H` is to display file names for `grep` matches.  Change the `*` to your own file glob/path expansion string if necessary.

Comment: `for ` enters into to endless loop

Answer (score 0):

Try with -c 2; with printing a context I see grep is separating its found o/p

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that numbers the results, adds a blank line between each result, trims each result's leading whitespace, and forces grep's colors to appear:

```
grep -Hrni "YOUR_SEARCH_TERM_HERE" * --color=always | awk -F: '{print "\n"NR ": " $0}' | awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

Usage example:

[image]