# new line separator for each grep result sh script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

Is there a way to have each result of grep followed by newline
for example if the result of grep is:

```
1
2
3
```

I need it to be:

```
1

2

3
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. If you haven't tried anything, look at `sed`.

Comment: OP asked for solutions that use grep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add blank line after every result in grep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8273636) and [grep command to add end line after every match](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20567667).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
grep "pattern" /path/to/file | awk '{print $0,"\n"}'
```

Comment: This does not work for multiline grep results, such as when the -C flag is used to print lines around the grep result

Comment: Could it be applied if the found pattern differs in different files