# grep command to add end line after every match

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

do you have any idea how to add some end line like

```
"=========================================================================================="
```

after every match

```
tail -f error.log -n 2000 | grep -B 10 -A 25 'Exception:'
```

this command prints all Exceptions log but i likes to see one seperator line for each exception log.

Comment: Hasn't `grep` already put a separator like `--` between matches for you as you're specifying `-A` and `-B` without `-o`?

Comment: @starrify that was my first thought, but the `grep` command produces 26 lines (10 before, 25 after) - and then OP wants a SINGLE line added. I'm not sure how to recognize that "block" (maybe awk, add separator every 36 lines).

Comment: @Floris Thank you for pointing that out. The same thought came to me and I edited my comment... Adding a separator every 36 lines is okay but still needs to process the first and last matches where there's no enough lines..

Comment: @starrify - I realized rather belatedly that your updated comment points directly to the solution I posted. Shout-out to you!

Answer (score 35):

You want the following option:

> --group-separator=SEP
>       Use  SEP  as  a group separator. By default SEP is double hyphen (--).

**Demo:**

```
$ cat file
before
exception 1
after
foo
bar
before
exception 2
after

$ grep -A 1 -B 1 --group-separator======================== exception file 
before
exception 1
after
=======================
before
exception 2
after
```

Comment: I learn something new on SO every day. Nice to get it out of the way first thing in the morning! This is clearly the right solution.

Comment: ...+1. However neigther `grep --help` nor `man 1 grep` gave options like that -- while it's okay to pass it to `grep` ><

Comment: @starrify FWIW, `grep` also has an option to _eliminate_ the separator, `--no-group-separator`.

Comment: @starrify Odd but true -- `man grep` doesn't list the option as you've already mentioned, but `info grep` does!

Comment: `unrecognized option: --group-separator` . `grep -V: 2.5.1` . What build are you using?

Comment: This is with `grep (GNU grep) 2.14` I can't be sure this option is supported on other variants *i.e.* `MAC/BSD grep`. The option is listed with `--help`, `man grep`, `info grep` on my system, strange it's supported and not documented for some of you.

Comment: sorry, i tried not working

Comment: It seemed not to work for me.. but then I fiddled around with the context a bit and saw the separator with certain settings.

Answer (score 4):

For people like myself who have a 'very old' grep that doesn't include the `--group-separator` option, the following seems to be an acceptable workaround.

Noticing that `grep` (my version, 2.5.1) does produce a "small, default" separator between groups (`--`), you can easily replace that string with a string of your choice:

```
tail -f rms.log -n 2000 | grep -B 10 -A 25 'Exception:' | sed 's/^--$/=================/'
```

This does replace the `--` with `============`

Obviously you can modify this to your liking. If you have the option of using `--group-separator` (@sudo_O's answer) that is obviously preferable.

**EDIT** reading the comments below the question, I realize that when @starrify updated his comment (which I had not noticed before) his comment essentially pointed directly to this solution - so I feel I own him a tip of the hat...

Comment: What version of `grep` are you using? On what platform? What output / error message do you get with this?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `sed` for text manipulation:

```
# cat test 
1
Exception
2
Exception
3
4
Exception
5
Exception
6
7
8
Exception
9



# sed -i '/Exception/a =========================' test 


# cat test 
1
Exception
=========================
2
Exception
=========================
3
4
Exception
=========================
5
Exception
=========================
6
7
8
Exception
=========================
9
```

Comment: AFAIK the OP is looking to select some number of lines before and after Exception and print the `====` lines at the end of each block, not simply print a `====` line after Exception.

Comment: i was looking for a way to grep something and add text to all matches using sed, this was helpful in that.

Comment: another way : `grep "match" | sed -n -e 's/match/match\/n=======/p'`

Answer (score 1):

You posted a command that doesn't do what you want and described it's output, but you didn't tell us what you DO want so this is a guess but maybe it'll be useful. It prints the 2 lines before and 3 lines after some regexp:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
FOO
e
f
g
h
i
j
FOO
k
l
m
n
o

$ awk -v re="FOO" -v b=2 -v a=3 'NR==FNR{line[FNR]=$0;next} $0 ~ re{for (i=(FNR-b);i<=(FNR+a);i++) print line[i]; print "=====" }' file file
c
d
FOO
e
f
g
=====
i
j
FOO
k
l
m
=====
```

Comment: Interesting - I had not used `-v` to import variables before. Makes this a very flexible solution. I like it!

Comment: You should always always use -v by default to int awk variables with external values. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for details.